# JQuery Equal Height in Rows Conflicts Only Works without Registering wp_footer();

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to make may own Wordpress theme. I want the scenario of blogpost lost DIVs blocks are equal in rows. I am using very cool JQuery tutorial from CSS-Tricks to make it happens. Here is the tutorial http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

I am enqueuing JQuery/JS in functions.php as follows :

```
// Load jQuery 
if ( !is_admin() ) { 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery',
    ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"),
    false); wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
}
// Load Equal Height .js 
function my_equal_height() 
{
    wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() .
    '/scripts/equalheight.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_equal_height');
```

But the result only works if I omit `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`. As we know that, it is not recommended to omit `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` while developing Wordpress theme.

Could somebody help me to solve this problem?

Any responds and helps will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close, I think these fixes should point you in the right direction. I went through and addressed some of your syntax issues and your conditional hooks. Hopefully this will get you rolling in the right direction.

```
// Load 'Working' jQuery 
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_register' );
// register from google and for footer
function jquery_register() {

    if ( is_admin() )
        return;

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', false, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

// Try this Equal height: 
function my_equal_height() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'equal_height', get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/equalheight.js', 'jquery', null, true );
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_equal_height' );
```

Let me know how this solution works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for quickly responding my question, David. 

I followed your stuff. It is very useful for me. The solution you give to me is 100% works. 

:)

Comment: Perfect Kharis, I'm glad that helped sort out your problems.

Comment: @KharisBlank You should then accept it as solution and maybe upvote the answer if it was written well.

Comment: @David Btw: Core has jQuery 1.7.1, so you're using a jQuery version that probably will break stuff and also deny the use of many new functions like `on()`.

Comment: Kaiser, yah, you're correct I hadn't even noticed he was originally using 1.4.1, good notice I'll edit that

Comment: @Kaiser, Thank you for your respond and notification. :)

Comment: Edited minor stuff.